# C: Using two static libs when one depends on the other one. VS12 How to connect between them

Tags: c

I have a application which uses a static library A. This static library A uses curl static library(B). On building the project in Visual Studio 2012 in Windows I get linkage errors of the curl api functions since they are not known to lib A. How do I connect between them so it passes linkage?

Comment: Why are `curl` functions not known to `A` if `A` uses them???

Comment: The normal rule is 'list LibraryA on the linker command line before LibraryB (the Curl library)'.  What command line did you use?  How were we supposed to guess that?

Comment: No commands. Trying to link using Visual Studio 2012 in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from gcc document:

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the
>   linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order
>   they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after
>   file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’,
>   those functions may not be loaded.

So, in your situation, static library A must appear before curl static library(B) like -lA -lB, otherwise library B will ignore by the compiler.